# Как оптимизировать размер виджета для мобильных устройств?

Tags: html, оптимизация

[image: пробелама]

Код виджета:

```
   <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6"> 
    <div id="vk_groups" style="width: 300px; height: 223px; background: none;">
     <iframe name="fXD5333d" frameborder="0" src="https://vk.com/widget_community.php?app=0&amp;width=540&amp;_ver=1&amp;gid=199535074&amp;mode=3&amp;color1=&amp;color2=&amp;color3=&amp;class_name=&amp;no_cover=1&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fbarsbot.ru%2F&amp;referrer=&amp;title=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%20Bot%20Gorilla&amp;16c0d4b6471" width="540" height="185" scrolling="no" id="vkwidget1" style="overflow: hidden; height: 223px;"></iframe>
    </div> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
                VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {
                    mode: 3,
                    no_cover: 1,
                    width: "auto"
                }, 199535074);
            </script> 
   </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Непонятно что ты вкладываешь в значение слова - оптимизировать... Судя по картинке ты тянешь сторонее API vk.

Comment: то есть подогнать виджет под форму оплаты. На телефоне он выезжает, на фото видно. Если поставить меньше размер то он уменьшится и на пк. Но форма оплаты как-то нормально и на пк и на телефоне... Виджет также надо